# go get on forked github repo got "unexpected module path" error

Tags: go, github, go-modules

I'm currently working something on AWS Cloudformation which using this repo https://github.com/awslabs/goformation. Because I did some customise so I made a fork https://github.com/vrealzhou/goformation.

Now in my other project (using go module) I'm trying to using `go get github.com/vrealzhou/goformation@v2.3.1` and I've got this error:

```bsh
go: github.com/vrealzhou/goformation@v0.0.0-20190513073615-ff3b65adb278: parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "github.com/awslabs/goformation"
go: error loading module requirements
```

Does anyone know the reason and how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: guess you only change master branch, not tag v2.3.1?

Comment: You a github fork is a new package with new import path and 100% unrelated to the original. YOu must rewrite all import in your fork.

Comment: @zzn My change was in add_features branch and tagged as v2.3.1. You can check my source.

Comment: @Volker I did what you've said in master with tag v2.3.2 already but still got the similar error when I run go get github.com/vrealzhou/goformation@v2.3.2

Comment: You must understand that you basically **cannot** "fork" (in the Github sense) a Go repo. What you can do is create a new package and everything in there must use the new package import path, starting from the go.mod and all imports. Probably you should not "customize" goformation but provide a wrapper.

Comment: You can use `replace` in your `go.mod` to do exactly what you're looking for - use a fork without updating imports or anything. I posted an answer with the updates needed for the `go.mod`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `replace` in your `go.mod` to use a fork instead of the upstream version. That way, you can make whatever modifications you need to the code without having to update the module path or import paths.

To be specific, in this case, you can do the following in your `go.mod` (I tested this by forking the repo, making a small change, and confirming it showed up):

```
require github.com/awslabs/goformation v1.4.1

replace github.com/awslabs/goformation => github.com/vrealzhou/goformation master
```

The first time you build or test, `master` will be replaced by the latest pseudo-version for your fork to make sure you get repeatable builds. The `replace` requires a specific version for the replacement.

Comment: I believe this is missing the `module` line at the top of the example. In this case, any module name will work as it is not published